# Cooja Simulator error: undefined symbol: log_printf Java Result: 127

Tags: java, undefined-symbol, contiki

I've been using cooja in a virtual machine. Since I needed more performance and productivity, I've been trying to run it in my physical machine.

Unfortunately everytime I start a simulation, Cooja closes and returns the error :

```
[javac] /home/**********/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/******/contiki/examples/my-udp-ipv6/obj_cooja/mtype222.cooja: undefined symbol: log_printf
[javac] Java Result: 127
```

I've tried to modify `log.c`, `Makefile.customrules-cooja` and `Makefile.customrules-cooja-ip64` and nothing has changed.

Comment: Well, what's *log_printf*? Is the path correct or bad java home env var?

Comment: "log_printf" is some kind of function. There are some procedures to convert it in "printf" within the mentioned files. I think "log_printf" replaces the common "printf" of C language in some simulations. But I really don't know what it is. I've just got the error and can't run simulations because of it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://forum.sa-mp.com/archive/index.php/t-421090-p-2.html - looks like something's actually missing. Never heard of contiki but try asking them why their example doesn't work? Good luck!

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you try jdk 1.7? - This looks like an JNI-issue.

Comment: @morty I followed your tip. Didn't work. I guess it's a problem in Cooja simulator itself..

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Contiki is a OS for WSN (wireless sensor networks). Cooja is a java-based simulator for Contiki. I've tried your tip. No answer yet.

Comment: @FranciscoKbçaJunior I'm afraid you'll have to provide more information. E.g. the source.